# How to prevent `debuild` from moving the `etc` folder out of the configured `--prefix` folder?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb

I'd like to build a Debian/Ubuntu package, that installs an app under the `./configure`'d `--prefix`.

When I run `./configure --prefix=/opt/d-ph/my_app && make && sudo make install`, then I end up with the following folder structure:

```
/opt/d-ph/my_app
 |- bin/(my binaries)
 |- etc/(my configuration)
 |- include/
 |- lib/
 |- share/
```

But when I run `debuild` with the following `debian/rules` override:

```
override_dh_auto_configure: 
    dh_auto_configure -- --prefix=/opt/d-ph/my_app
```

then I end up with the following package structure:

```
 |- /DEBIAN
 |- /etc/(my configuration)
 |- /opt/d-ph/my_app
     |- bin/(my binaries)
     |- include/
     |- lib/
     |- share/
 |- /share/
```

I don't want my package to install its configuration (i.e. the `/etc` folder) under the `/etc` root directory. I.e. I'd like the configuration to reside in the directory specified by the `--prefix` option. I.e. I'd like the following package structure to be generated:

```
|- /DEBIAN
|- /opt/d-ph/my_app
    |- bin/(my binaries)
    |- etc/(my configuration)
    |- include/
    |- lib/
    |- share/     
|- /share/
```

How can I prevent `debuild` from moving the `etc` folder out of the configured `--prefix` folder, when preparing the package directory structure?

Comment: Doing so would violate important parts of the FHS and other applicable standards.  What do you hope to achieve by breaking this?

Comment: Perhaps the last intrusive workaround would be to put symlinks in `/etc` to the files and directories you want to have in `/opt/d-ph/my_app/etc`.

Comment: I'd like to build a deb package for the latest stable release of an application (not mine). The application in the distro's repo (Ubuntu 14.04) is too old (and there are no PPAs for it). I decided, that I don't want to install the app under the `/usr` prefix, because I don't want to maintain any binary incompatibilities. Instead, I want to build a portable-like .deb release of this app for my own use. This .deb should not touch anything system-wide. That's why I don't want to store the config in the root `/etc`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with overriding the `dh_installdeb` build step. I essentially revert it's moving of the `etc` folder back under the configured `--prefix`.

```
APP_PREFIX=/opt/d-ph/my_app
ETC_DIR_PATH=$(CURDIR)/debian/my_app/etc

(...)

override_dh_installdeb:
    dh_installdeb

    # move the /etc folder
    if [ -d $(ETC_DIR_PATH) ]; then mv $(ETC_DIR_PATH) $(CURDIR)/debian/my_app$(APP_PREFIX); fi

    # tell dpkg not to look for the etc files anymore
    > $(CURDIR)/debian/my_app/DEBIAN/conffiles
```

As @tripleee commented under the question, it's probably not good to do this, so do it at your own risk. It works for me, though, and that's all that matters to me (the resulting `.deb` package is for my personal use only)